# ionic scope won't update inside function

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to get my location using cordova geolocation plugin and my controller look like:

```
.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope,$cordovaGeolocation,$ionicLoading) {

    $scope.location="location";
    $ionicLoading.show({
        template: '<ion-spinner icon="bubbles"></ion-spinner><br/>Acquiring location!'
    });

    var posOptions = {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        timeout: 15000,
        maximumAge: 0
    };

    $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(posOptions).then(function (position) {
        var lat  = position.coords.latitude;
        var lng = position.coords.longitude;

        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
        var request = {
          latLng: latlng
        };
        geocoder.geocode(request, function(data, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            if (data[3] != null) {

              $scope.location=data[3].formatted_address;
              console.log($scope.location);
            } else {
              console.log("No address available");
            }

          }

        })

        $ionicLoading.hide();           

    }, function(err) {
        $ionicLoading.hide();
        console.log(err);
    });
})
```

In the View, the value of `$scope.location` is still "location" although it already updated inside geocoder function. But when I show it in console log, it shows my current city. Can anyone help me?

Here is my HTML

```
  <ion-content scroll="true" ng-controller="HomeCtrl">
    <h3>{{location}}</h3>
  </ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `$scope.$apply();` after `$scope.location=data[3].formatted_address;` ...should force a scope update.